# How to make global menu always shown on unmaximized window in unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using indicator-appmenu in maximized mode only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37090/using-indicator-appmenu-in-maximized-mode-only)

User don't need to hover top panel to see application menus. But if application maximized, user need to hover top panel to see it's menus (like current unity behavior).

Thanks