# How can you get the menu bar to act differently for maximized and small windows in unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using indicator-appmenu in maximized mode only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37090/using-indicator-appmenu-in-maximized-mode-only)

When the window is maximized the menu of that application is in the global menu, but on a small window the menu would be nice to remain with the window (old school).

How you can do that? It's really annoying if you work with a small window on the lower side of the screen specially if you use a touchpad.

Comment: I already asked this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/37090/using-indicator-appmenu-in-maximized-mode-only so possibly no way to do it unless you want to remove appmenu completely

Comment: +1 to this question. Have you filed a bug?